# "adb shell getprop persist.sys.country" returning empty string

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to get from the device (running android L) the country and the language with the following commands:

```
adb shell getprop persist.sys.country
adb shell getprop persist.sys.language
```

But both return a empty string.

When I try another getprop command, like:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.model
```

It returns the correct value.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: did you found any solution

Comment: Yes, actually depending on your android version, those variables path/names can change. So you need to check where this information is stored depending on the android target version you are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

Android has changed this prop name in the last versions. You can use now:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.locale
```

or

```
adb shell getprop persist.sys.locale
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some other useful commands related to this question:

```
adb shell getprop ro.csc.country_code  //e.g. [Germany] 
adb shell getprop ro.csc.countryiso_code //e.g. [DE]
adb shell getprop ro.csc.sales_code //e.g. [VD2]
```

It gives information about country and operator the Binary is dedicated to (if not modified of course).